# Solution to a Cauchy-Euler ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE:
$$x^2 y'' + x y’ + y = f(x) ~.$$ I am trying to find a way to express the solution $$u(x)=u(\text{particular})+u(\text{homogeneous})$$ to the boundary value problem $$u(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}) = u_1$$ and  $$u(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}) = u_2$$

I’ve found $~u(\text{homogeneous})~$ to be $A\cos{(\ln(t))} $.

But I’m not sure how to express $~u(\text{particular})~$ as $~f(x)~$ is an arbitrary function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need two fundamental solutions for the homogeneous equation.  Thus $A \cos(\ln(t)) + B \sin(\ln(t))$, not just $A \cos(\ln(t))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters), with the result

$$ u_{\text particular}(x) = \sin(\ln(x)) \int \dfrac{\cos(\ln(x)) f(x)}{x}\; dx - \cos(\ln(x)) \int \dfrac{\sin(\ln(x)) f(x)}{x}\; dx $$

Answer (score 0):

Given that $$x^2 y'' + x y’ + y = f(x) ~\tag1$$
Taking $~x=e^z~\implies z=\ln x$

Then $$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\cdot \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{dy}{dz}\implies xy'=Dy\qquad \text{where}\quad D\equiv \frac{d}{dz}$$
Similarly $$x^2y''=D(D-1)y$$
From $(1)$, $$\{D(D-1)+D+1\}y=f(e^z)$$
$$\implies (D^2+1)y=f(e^z)$$

Now $$~y(\text{homogeneous})~=A\cos z+B\sin z=A\cos(\ln x)+B\sin(\ln x)$$where $~A,~B~$ are constants.

Again $$~y(\text{particular})~=\frac{1}{D^2+1}~f(e^z)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{D-i}-\frac{1}{D+i}\right)~f(e^z)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{D-i}~f(e^z)-\frac{1}{D+i}~f(e^z)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}\int f(e^z)~e^{-iz}~dz-e^{-iz}\int f(e^z)~e^{iz}~dz\right)$$
Since $~f(x)=f(e^z)~$  is an arbitrary function (we take $~f(e^z)~$ as $~D~$ is function of $~z~$), so after solving this replace $~z~$ by $~\ln x~$ and we get the desired  $~y(\text{particular})~$.

After that the general solution is given by $$y(x)=y(\text{particular})+y(\text{homogeneous})$$

Constants $~A,~B~$ can be determined from the given condition $$y(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}) = y_1\qquad \text{and}\qquad y(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}) = y_2~.$$

*************.****************

**For example:** Take $$f(x)=\tan (\ln x)\implies f(e^z)=\tan z$$
So $$~y(\text{particular})~=\frac{1}{D^2+1}~\tan z$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{D-i}-\frac{1}{D+i}\right)~\tan z$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{D-i}~\tan z-\frac{1}{D+i}~\tan z\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}\int \tan z~e^{-iz}~dz-e^{-iz}\int \tan z~e^{iz}~dz\right)\tag2$$
Now $$e^{iz}\int \tan z~e^{-iz}~dz=e^{iz}\int (\cos z~-~i~\sin z)~\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}~dz$$
$$=e^{iz}\int [\sin z~-~i~(\sec z~-~\cos z)]~dz$$
$$=e^{iz}~ \left[-\cos z~-~i~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)~+~i~\sin z)\right]$$
$$=-~e^{iz}~ \left[e^{-iz}~+~i~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)\right]$$
Therefore $$e^{iz}\int \tan z~e^{-iz}~dz=-~ \left[1~+~i~e^{iz}~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)\right]$$
Similarly , $$e^{-iz}\int \tan z~e^{iz}~dz=-~ \left[1~-~i~e^{-iz}~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)\right]$$
Hence $(2)$ gives $$y(\text{particular})~=~\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{iz}\int \tan z~e^{-iz}~dz-e^{-iz}\int \tan z~e^{iz}~dz\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}\left\{-i~(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})~~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)\right\}$$
$$=-~\cos z~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{z}{2}\right)$$
$$=-~\cos (\ln x)~\ln \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\ln x}{2}\right)$$